# MEF is not Importing the same instance

Tags: c#, mef

I'm trying to test MEF's single instance composition feature. The export happens with `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]` and imports happen as `[ImportMany(typeof(IPartOfThePuzzle), RequiredCreationPolicy = CreationPolicy.Shared)]`.

I was running the test and importing the same part from two different classes within a console app. However, the two instances of IPartOfThePuzzle implementation do not appear to be the same. It appears that MEF is re-instantiating the object in the second call.

Below is what I have.

Part1.DLL:

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
[Export(typeof(IPartOfThePuzzle))]
class Piece1 : IPartOfThePuzzle
{
    string _prop1;
    public string SomeProp { get => _prop1; set => _prop1 = value; }
    public Piece1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Piece1 instantiated, setting Prop value to 'First Part " +
            "Original Value'");
        _prop1 = "First Part Original Value";
    }
}
```

Part2.DLL:

```
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
[Export(typeof(IPartOfThePuzzle))]
class Piece2 : IPartOfThePuzzle
{
    string _prop1;
    public string SomeProp { get => _prop1; set => _prop1 = value; }
    public Piece2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Piece2 instantiated, setting Prop value to 'Second Part " +
            "Original Value'");
        _prop1 = "Second Part Original Value";
    }
}
```

Console.exe > GetParts.cs

```
public class GetParts
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IPartOfThePuzzle))]
    public IPartOfThePuzzle[] Pieces { get; set; }

    public GetParts()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(
            new DirectoryCatalog(
                @"C:\PuzzlePieces"
            )
        );
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

Console.exe > GetPartsAgain.cs

```
public class GetPartsAgain
{
    [ImportMany(typeof(IPartOfThePuzzle))]
    public IPartOfThePuzzle[] Pieces { get; set; }
    public GetPartsAgain()
    {
        var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();
        catalog.Catalogs.Add(
            new DirectoryCatalog(
                @"C:\PuzzlePieces"
            )
        );
        CompositionContainer container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
        container.ComposeParts(this);
    }
}
```

and finally, Console.exe > Program.cs

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    GetParts firstImport = new GetParts();
    Console.WriteLine($"Initial value from First Import: {firstImport.Pieces[0].SomeProp}");
    firstImport.Pieces[0].SomeProp = "First Import Overwritten Value";
    Console.WriteLine($"Overwritten from First Import: {firstImport.Pieces[0].SomeProp}");
    Console.WriteLine("-  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -");
    GetPartsAgain secondImport = new GetPartsAgain();
    Console.WriteLine($"Value from Second Import: {secondImport.Pieces[0].SomeProp}");

    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Console output:

[image]

The output shows that the Pieces were instantiated both times (once for GetParts and once for GetPartsAgain). The documentation, blogs and online forums said this was the way to prevent multiple instances but I think I am missing something in my understanding. Can you help me understand what that is?

Comment: You have two independent containers. Each container will generate its own single instances. You're using the MEF container in a wrong way. A part should not instantiate its own container.

Comment: ok, so if I need to import one of the parts in multiple places within my application, would the container instance then need to be a singleton (or at least somehow be the same container instance throughout the app)?

Comment: An application should have only one container in most cases. Sometimes multiple (scoped) containers can be used, but it's a very specialized case. The container instance shouldn't be a singleton and shouldn't be exposed at all. Instantiate the container at the application entry point - it's then called the composition root. Actually, MEF is very well documented. You should maybe start with reading the docs.

Comment: got it, I might have missed that. thanks